# Splitting Long running SQL query into multiple smaller queries

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Java 6 / Spring jdbc.

We have a table with records count ~60mn.

We need to load this entire table into memory, but firing select * on this table takes hours to complete.

So I am splitting the query as below

```
String query = "  select * from TABLE where "  ;
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(query).append(" (sk_table_id % 10) =").append(i);
            service.submit(new ParallelCacheBuilder(builder.toString(),namedParameters,jdbcTemplate));
        }
```

basically, I am splitting the query by adding a where condition on primary key column,

above code snippet splits the query into 10 queries running in parallel.this uses java's [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

I am not a SQL expert, but I guess above queries will need to load same data in memory before applyinh modulo operator on primary column.

Is this good/ bad/ best/worst way? Is there any other way, please post.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think its a bad idea to load entire data to memory. You should consider using stored procedures!

Comment: @Sandy I agree, but how procedures will help to reduce timing, can you please guide ?

Comment: Why do you need to load all records? Why does it take several hours? I would check the fetch size, and also check how the query is executed.

Comment: is this query used to fetch records to cache it?

Comment: @Kaj We are building in memory DB so I need entire table in memory, It takes 1.25-1.5 hrs to load depending upon the load on DB, which fetch size you are referring to java / sql server

Answer (score 1):

If you do need all the 60M records in memory, `select * from ...` is the fastest approach. Yes, it's a full scan; there's no way around. It's disk-bound so multithreading won't help you any. Not having enough memory available (swapping) will kill performance instantly. Data structures that take significant time to expand will hamper performance, too.

Open the Task Manager and see how much CPU is spent; probably little; if not, profile your code or just comment out everything but the reading loop. Or maybe it's a bottleneck in the network between the SQL server and your machine.

Maybe SQL Server can offload data faster to an external dump file of known format using some internal pathways (e.g. Oracle can). I'd explore the possibility of dumping a table into a file and then parsing that file with C#; it could be faster e.g. because it won't interfere with other queries that the SQL server is serving at the same time.

Comment: Thanks ,but I did observe reduction in load time to 40-50% by running queries in parallel (as listed in post), though I am not able to understand why?

Comment: The speedup is a rather strange effect for me. Maybe it's due to the network round-trip time? Anyway, you could use it! I'd experiment with the number of threads to see which number gives most gain. Also, you can try to collect a bunch of records in an array in a stored procedure and fetch that bunch in one go, even if you just glue everything together as a large string which you then split in C# code. Also take a look at [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) and its bulk export mode; maybe it's still faster via a temp file.